# Django custom login form returns None

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to authenticate a user by using a custom login form, but authenticate() returns None.

I created a custom login form template, an index view which shows the login form to unauthenticated users and another template to authenticated ones, I "mapped" the appropriate URLs to the desired views functions and added some debug messages with print to know in which part of the code the flow stops.

In views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_active and request.user.is_authenticated:
        print(request.user)
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='groupname').exists():
            print('does have groups')
        else:
            print('doesnot have groups')
        return render(request, 'generic_pages\\index_and_login\\menu1.html', {})
    else:
        return render(request, 'generic_pages\\index_and_login\\generic_login.html', {})

def login_user(request):
    print('We are in login_user')
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        print('We know we have a POST request')
        username = request.POST['login'][0]
        password = request.POST['login'][1]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(user) #Prints the user object
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            print('We know user is active')
            login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^login', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    re_path(r'^logout', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    re_path(r'^.*/$', views.handler404, name='handler404'),
]
```

In generic_login.html

```
{% load static %}
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'generic_pages/index_and_login/css/generic_login.css' %}" >

<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
  <div id="formContent">
    <div class="fadeIn first">
      <img src="{% static 'generic_pages/index_and_login/images/slot1.png' %}" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
    </div>

    <form method="POST" action="/login/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="login">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the debug screen output, where I can see that authenticate() returns None...

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 18, 2019 - 15:27:38
Django version 2.2.1, using settings 'vpSlots_django.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
We are in login_user
We know we have a POST request
None
[18/May/2019 15:28:24] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/May/2019 15:28:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1074
```

**EDIT**
I changed the html names of username and password, as advised, I changed my views also like below. I am updating the debug too. Still, i get None.

Updated views.py

```
def login_user(request):
    print('We are in login_user')
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        print('We know we have a POST request')
        print(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['login']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print("User/Pass: ", username, "/", password)
        user = authenticate(request.POST)
        print(user) #Prints the user object
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            print('We know user is active')
            login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Updated login page template

```
{% load static %}
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'generic_pages/index_and_login/css/generic_login.css' %}" >

<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
  <div id="formContent">
    <div class="fadeIn first">
      <img src="{% static 'generic_pages/index_and_login/images/slot1.png' %}" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
    </div>

    <form method="POST" action="/login/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="login">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated debug log

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 18, 2019 - 16:01:18
Django version 2.2.1, using settings 'vpSlots_django.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
We are in login_user
We know we have a POST request
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['FvxrtNJllBAqfh7Ir8qK9nCu4gWyeNCb33XRPcJs5PQNb6h6tASiHDDRedWaRUpp'], 'login': ['Player01'], 'password': ['rascal123']}>
User/Pass:  Player01 / rascal123
None
[18/May/2019 16:01:26] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/May/2019 16:01:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1077
```

Comment: Why do the username and password inputs have the same `name` attribute? You seem to be assuming the "name" field of the POST data gets both attributes - but I'm not sure if this is the case. Try it with 2 different names for the fields. (If you're not sure what's going on, of course you can always try `print(username)` and `print(password)` to see what is actually being read.

Comment: @RobinZigmond updated my question, can you please check?

Comment: check what? I can't run your project locally from these few details, and I certainly don't know which users are in your database. But it appears from your edit that all the data is being passed correctly, in which case it seems that no user with that username and password has been registered.

Comment: @RobinZigmond the user is created from Django Admin manually. I can certainly verify that the user exist.. Unfortunately.

Comment: `user = authenticate(request.POST)` should be as previously, `user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)`

Comment: @Gasanov that solved my issue! Thank you!

Comment: Do you guys know if the csrf token is taking place, or if it's useless the way i do it?

Comment: Not useless. But you shouldn't render fields manually, use [AuthenticationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm)